# How to pass an argument to a function in data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have two variables inside my layout file :

```
<data>
  <variable name="createExpenseViewModel" type="com.lionosur.dailyexpenses.viewModels.MainViewModel"/>
  <variable name="createExpenseConverter" type="com.lionosur.dailyexpenses.converters.createExpenseActivityConverter.Companion"/>
</data>
```

My view model has an method to return the live data :

```
fun getAllExpenseItems(): LiveData<List<Expense>> {
    return expenseRepository.getAllExpenseItems()
}
```

I need to observe this data and populate an spinner,

```
class createExpenseActivityConverter {
    // contains all the static methods to convert the data for the ui
    companion object {

        fun getExpenseCategoryListFromSource(list:List<Source>):ArrayList<String> {
            val categoryItems = ArrayList<String>()
            categoryItems.addAll(list.map { it.sourceName })
            return categoryItems
        }
    }
}
```

to populate a spinner I need to supply an array list of string

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expense_category"
        android:entries="@{()-> createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1) }"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
/>
```

in **android:entries** I need to convert the observed data to array list of string, how do I pass the `@{()-> createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1) }` result in to another static method `createExpenseViewConverter.getExpenseCategoryListFromSource(sourceList)` which would return a array list of string.

in my activity i have setup binding like this

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_create_expense)



val mainViewModel =  DaggerExpenseComponent.builder()
    .setContext(this)
    .build()
    .getExpenseViewModel()

binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
binding.createExpenseViewModel = mainViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use below syntax for that :

```
android:entries="@{createExpenseConverter.getExpenseCategoryListFromSource(createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1))}"
```

Here, what we've done is accessed your input from `MainViewModel` object **createExpenseViewModel** using `getAllSourceItems()` method;

And then passing it to another class `createExpenseActivityConverter` object **createExpenseConverter** using method `getExpenseCategoryListFromSource()` which returns you `ArrayList<String>` that your spinner requires.

---

**Edit:**

When you use `LiveData` in **DataBinding**, Data-binding Compiler takes care of refreshing data just like **ObservableFields**. All you need to do is provide your `LifeCycleOwner` to your databinding object.

For Example:

If your activity has `ViewDataBinding` let's say **mActivityBinding** using which you provide your `ViewModel` to set `LiveData` in xml binding, then after setting your `ViewModel` consider setting `LifecycleOwner` like below code :

```
//Some Activity having data-binding
... onCreate() method of activity
    mActivityBinding.setViewModel(myViewModel);
    mAcivityBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this); // Providing this line will help you observe LiveData changes from ViewModel in data-binding.
...
```

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setlifecycleowner)

Comment: createExpenseViewModel.getAllSourceItems(1) return live data, dont i need to observe it?

Comment: No, it would be handled by Data binding compiler internally.

Comment: because it returns null and spinner is not populated for me, i have used your answer.

Comment: Even if you want to observe livedata, just use this line in your respective activity/fragment : `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` on your binding object in `onCreate()` after setting up all variables.

Comment: the problem is i want  to know what is the syntax to observer live data in data binding, and use the observed value in to a converter